# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'

Tags: python, oop, scope

I'm trying to understand an error message I am receiving (Question subject line). I suspect it may have to do with scope and nesting logic.

Here's the code block in question:

```
class Smaug(Scene):

def enter(self):
    print "Smaug is a terrifying huge fire breathing dragon, but you must get the Arkenstone from him for Thorin"       
    print "In Smaug's cave, the Lonely Mountain, Smaug notices your presence and challenges you to a game"
    print "He says \"Guess a number between 1 and 3\""
    smaugNum = random.randint(1, 3)
    guesses = 0

    def guess():

        while guesses < 4:
            print "Guess a number between 1 and 3"
            numb = raw_input("> ")

            if numb == smaugNum:
                print "Well done! You win."
                Player.BilbosStuff.append('arkenstone')
                print "Now Bilbo has", Player.BilbosStuff
                return 'finished'

            else:
                print "You lose!"
                guesses += 1
                guess()

        print "Too many failed guesses, you lose!"
        return 'death'
```

This block of code is run with an engine, which is a class:

```
class GameEngine(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.scenes = {'TheTrolls':TheTrolls(), 'MistyMountainsAndGollum':MistyMountainsAndGollum(), 'Smaug':Smaug(), 'death':death()}

    def run(self):

        next = 'TheTrolls'
        while True:
            if next == 'finished':
                print "Well done! You won!"
                exit(1)
            next = self.scenes.get(next).enter()


GameEngine().run()
```

The "game" (It's a tutorial I am working through) did work before adding the guess() function to Smaug().

But here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ex45.py", line 21, in
<module>
    GameEngine().run()   File "ex45.py", line 18, in run
    next = self.scenes.get(next).enter() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

My line of thought was along the lines that maybe `return 'finished'` in the while loop was not a return of the parent block? Or am I way off? I'm a learner.

Comment: You need to tab in the code...

Comment: Couldn't it be the indentation? It seems to me "def enter(self)" is at the same level than class Smaug...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I checked but I think that that's just Stack Overflow auto formatting when I paste - def enter(self): is indented from the parent

Comment: *Please* fix your code's indentation.

Comment: It looks like sometimes `self.scenes.get(next)` returns `None`. Are you sure you always return something that will be in your scene dictionary?

Comment: Downvoters, please at least say why? Perhaps I can edit or update the Q

Comment: Downvoted because this is extremely basic debugging. You're trying to `get` a key that's not in the dictionary (`get` returns `None`); which means your `next` variable has a wrong value somewhere. Simply add a print statement before the line giving you the error and you will see the wrong scene name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, in code form:

```
if next not in scenes:
    scenes.get(next) == None
```

Hence the error: as the message tells you, `None` does not have an `enter` attribute! Try

```
next = scenes.get(next)
if next is not None:
    next.enter()
else:
    print("No more scenes")
    break # leave the loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that created an infinite loop "No more scenes".

Comment: or `try: next = self.scenes.get(next).enter(); except AttributeError: print("No more scenes"); break`

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the error that `self.scenes.get(next)` results in `None`. There can be many reasons but I guess it's the `death()` call returning None.

Comment: Why would the death call return none? it exists in the dict and is (should be) returned when the condition for the while loop to run is false

Comment: You have `self.scenes = {'TheTrolls':TheTrolls(), 'MistyMountainsAndGollum':MistyMountainsAndGollum(), 'Smaug':Smaug(), 'death':death()}` and as i said `self.scenes.get(something)` returns None. All other values in the dict seem to be class instances, so that leaves only `death()`.